# smcure Error in while (convergence > eps & i < emmax) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I get this error while using smcure. I don't have missing values in my data, no null data and enough observations in each variable to be able to fit the model. Moreover, all my data is numerical or logical( the package does not allow for categorical data) and the data is contained in a dataframe.I traced back where it goes wrong and apparently duric the logistic regression part of the model, the parameters are estimated too high. Therefore `exp(b*t(Z))` becomes `Inf` and `uncureprob=exp(b*t(Z))/(1+exp(b*t(Z)))` calculates infinity/infity which gives an NaN value (cfr.logistic regression). The data looks like this

And the commant looks like this
[image: data]
Does anybody know why this happens? I also get this warning message " In addition: Warning message: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge "[image]